# RSA using 2 as a public exponent

Tags: rsa, public-key

I'm failing to see why 2 can never be used and what weaknesses would be associated with doing so.

There's a similar question asking why it has to be in the form of $2^n$+1 but why not $2^n$

Comment: $gcd(2,(p-1)(q-1)) =$?

Comment: if p is odd a q is even it will be 1. if both are odd/both are even it will be 2?

Comment: right of course! *facepalm* OK so what weakness would that bring?
Edit: scratch that, it would lead to any ct no being uniquely decryptable

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem

Comment: The public exponent merely has to be relatively prime to λ(*modulus*), where  λ is the Carmichael function. It is often chosen to be near a power of two because such an exponent eliminates all but one of the multiplies in the standard binary exponentiation square-and-multiply algorithm.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It is not that RSA becomes *insecure* when used with public exponent $2$. (In fact, the [Rabin Cryptosystem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rabin_cryptosystem) does exactly that.) It's that it *doesn't  actually work*.

The problem is that for $N = pq$ for two primes $p$ and $q$, the function $f : x \mapsto x^2 \bmod N$ is not injective. So it is impossible to invert uniquely. In fact, most elements of the function's range (the set of perfect squares) have $4$ preimages under $f$. (As pointed out by Thomas Pornin, the multiples of $p$ and $q$ have $2$, while $0$ has only one.)

We can get around this problem by choosing $p\equiv q\equiv 3 \bmod 4$ and restricting the domain to the set of quadratic residues. In this case, the function is a trapdoor permutation over the set of quadratic residues if factoring is hard.

One might note, that this is actually a *better* guarantee than the one we have for the RSA trapdoor permutation, where the security is not known to be implied by the hardness of factoring.

Comment: Technically, _most_ elements have 4 square roots, but some have only two, and zero has only one. The elements that have only two square roots are the non-zero elements that happen to be a multiple of either $p$ or $q$. Of course, it is extremely improbable to hit one such element out of (bad) luck.

Comment: @ThomasPornin You are of course correct.

Comment: The last sentence might be worth emphasizing: unlike RSA, the Rabin cryptosystem is provably as hard as factoring (i.e. breaking it provides efficient factoring as a side effect).

Comment: @R.. I left that out because it did not seem particularly relevant to the question being asked, but I added a comment about it now.

Comment: @Maeher: Thanks. I think it's nice because it confirms whatever suspicion the OP had that 2 is actually an interesting and productive choice of exponent.

Answer (score 1):

I had this question in my homework and here how I answer it

When we want to pick $d$ as a private key, we calculate it by

$ed = 1\ mod\ \phi(n)$ this means d is modular multiplicative inverse of e in mod $\phi(n)$

and $\phi(n) = (p-1).(q-1)$, $p$ and $q$ are prime numbers.

$\phi(n)$ is always an odd number if $e=2$, $gcd(2,\phi(n)) \neq 1 $ so there is no modular multiplicative inverse of e in mod $\phi(n)$. this means we cant calculate $d$

This method can be used for all numbers with the form of $2^n$